# Why is dynamic binding not working the way I expect it to in the following code?

Tags: c#

I've read the following statement about dynamic binding:

> Which method to invoke is determined by variable's actual type and not declared type. This is known as dynamic binding.

But then why is the following code not working the way I expect it to?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.SomeMethod(); // overriden 
        parent.AnotherMethod(); // hidden

        Child child = new Child();
        child.SomeMethod();
        child.AnotherMethod();

        System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");

        Parent parent1 = new Child();
        parent1.SomeMethod();
        parent1.AnotherMethod();


    }
}

class Parent
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod() //override
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent.SomeMethod");
    }

    public void AnotherMethod() //hide
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent.AnotherMethod");
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public override void SomeMethod() //overriden
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Child.SomeMethod");
    }

    public new void AnotherMethod() //hidden
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Child.AnotherMethod");
    }

}
```

The output of the above code is:

> Parent.SomeMethod
>
> Parent.AnotherMethod
>
> Child.SomeMethod
>
> Child.AnotherMethod

---

> Child.SomeMethod
>
> Parent.AnotherMethod <-- **Shouldn't this be Child.SomeMethod? I'm confused please explain**

Answer (score 2):

From [New Vs Override](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65e02299-300f-4b74-8f0a-679f490605f5/new-vs-override-?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

> You cannot override a non-virtual or static method. The overridden base method must be virtual, abstract, or override.

From [new modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)

Answer (score 2):

You are upcasting variable `parent1` back to class type `Parent` in this assignment:

```
Parent parent1 = new Child();
```

Because `AnotherMethod` isn't polymorphic (since you haven't applied `virtual` / `override`), and in fact you've explicitly added the `new` keyword to tell the compiler that the `AnotherMethod` symbol is reused between `Child` and `Parent` (i.e. There's no dynamic binding on `AnotherMethod`).

As a result, compiler will resolve the Parent's `AnotherMethod` symbol at compile time because of the variable type (`Parent parent1`), irrespective of the fact that the actual run time type allocated on the heap is a `Child` instance.

You can access the Child `AnotherMethod` by using another downcast:

```
((Child)parent1).AnotherMethod();
```