# OOP Method hidden and overloaded

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm new to programming. I study books. Sometimes some examples raise questions. I ask for help, the explanation on the Habr is not very clear.
Found an example [on a habr](https://habr.com/ru/article/474182/) - the fourth question on C#.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x1 = new C(); 
            x1.Print(); //C

            B x2 = new C(); 
            x2.Print(); //C

            A x3 = new C(); 
            x3.Print(); //A
        }
    }



    class A
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        new public virtual void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }

    class C : B
    {
        override public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }
```

**Explained as follows:**
In the first call, “C” will be displayed, since for var the compiler will infer the type of the object from the right side of the expression, and this will be type C. **// Everything is clear with that.**

For the second call, the value “C” will also be displayed, since the CLR will determine that the actual type of the object is C, and will invoke the necessary virtual method overload. **//So...**

**//Further a little incomprehensible**
In the third case, “A” will be displayed, since the declaration of the B.Print method (and hence its overloading in C) hides the A.Print method. Accordingly, the CLR does not consider B.Print and C.Print to be overloads and calls a class A method.

I’m already trying to describe step by step what is happening in the context of the stack and the heap:

**x2:**

- on the heap memory is allocated for an instance of class C;
- default constructor writes an instance of class C to this section;
- a link to this piece of memory is written to the variable x2 (type B) on the stack, this is possible because B is the base class for C;
- Next, you need to decide which Print method of all Print methods will be called and why.
  The CLR looks at the type of the variable and tries to call the method by type, that is, in the case of x2 it is B.Print (), but since the link we have is an instance of class C, and for it **there is** overload **of this** method, then C.Print () method is called;

**x3:**

- on the heap memory is allocated for an instance of class C;
- default constructor writes an instance of class C to this section;
- a link to this piece of memory is written to the variable x3 (type A) on the stack, this is possible because A is the base class for B, B is the base class for C;
- Next, you need to decide which Print method of all Print methods will be called and why.
  The CLR looks at the type of the variable and tries to call the method by type, that is, in the case of x3 it is A.Print (), but since the link we have is an instance of class C, and for it **there is no** overload **of this** method, then A.Print () method is called.

1) Is my description true? If not, please explain with this example how it works.

2) Do you fully agree with the explanation of the answer on the Habr or would you remove / add / replace something?

Comment: Yes, your explanation looks correct. Don't about attached link explanation, it's on Russian, it's better to link English version or ask on ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Thank you. The difference in translation is not noticeable. I already asked in the Russian version, everything was somehow sluggish there.

Comment: [Related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59541044)

Comment: Does this question help?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45872841/47589

Comment: @Eric Lippert could give us some light on this particular scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, judging by how it works and the links, my explanation is correct.

*The runtime (not the compiler) works out which version of method to call when invoking it through a **variable**, based on the **real type of the object  referenced** by this **variable**.* (MS Visual C# Step by Step 9ed, CHAPTER 12
Working with inheritance)

[Why is dynamic binding not working the way I expect it to in the following code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541044/why-is-dynamic-binding-not-working-the-way-i-expect-it-to-in-the-following-code)

[Will CLR check the whole inheritance chain to determine which virtual method to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872841/will-clr-check-the-whole-inheritance-chain-to-determine-which-virtual-method-to)

Answer (score 1):

As in class B is written 'new' keyword in print function declaration, its brokes the inheritance connection between A and C print functions.

Comment: Thank you, this is understandable, but what happens next and why, how it works. I was interested in the mechanism why the A.Print () method is called. And I tried to explain how. Now you need to understand whether this is so.